# color sides in convex Hull

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, mesh

I'm using this code to show the convex hull.

I want to give every sides color because I'm doing some changes in convex hull and I need to see every sides alone.

```
  ClearAll["Global`*"]
M = x^4 + x y z + y^4 + z^4 + x^2 z^2
p = CoefficientRules[M, {x, y, z}][[All, 1]]
chull = ConvexHullMesh[p];
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05], Black, 
   Map[Text[#, # + {0., 0, 0.1}] &, p]}]
   , Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Another step:
Can I cut part of the convex hull (or can I just see part of convex hull)
because in my work I will just focus on the part from the view from (0,0,0)
[image: Here is two view for the convex hull]

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but your convex hull mesh has six 2D faces. It might be easier to work with if you drop the unnecessary point `{2, 0, 2}`. So `q = Drop[p, {2}]; newchull = ConvexHullMesh[q];` will give you a mesh with the expected four faces. Of course, you may _want_ 6 faces. In which case, nevermind.

Comment: @aardvark2012 thank you for your comment, but {2,0,2} will not count because it is on the plane. however, I need a part of the convex hull because when I have a system of equations i will face many planes on my convex hull then I need something call the main part of my work which is the part from the view from the point (0,0,0).

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica graphics always have a corresponding `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` expression. i.e. functions like `Plot` and `ConvexHull` don't generate graphics, they generate *code*. We can take the code and adapt it as required. The code can usually be seen using `FullForm`, but in this case we also need to use `Show`:

```
(gr = chull // Show) // FullForm
```

Note in the output of the preceding expression the following:

```
Annotation[
 Polygon[List[List[1, 3, 4], List[3, 5, 4], List[4, 5, 2], 
   List[5, 3, 2], List[3, 1, 2], List[1, 4, 2]]], "Geometry"]
```

This is clearly the polygons in the figure. (The coordinates are integers which are translated into coordinates by `GraphicsComplex`, which wraps this expression.) Here is how we can change this expression to color the sides:

```
gr /. RuleDelayed[
  Annotation[Polygon[polygons__List], "Geometry"],
  Annotation[
   MapIndexed[{ColorData[97, First[#2]], Polygon[#]} &, polygons]]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The operations that you apply to these polygons are arbitrary. You can also use it to remove planes as what you ask for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new in mathematica can you please write the full code of my equation. The idea that I'm working on convex hull and I want to see the view of (0,0,0) with color which exactly the one you add in your answer.

Comment: @AteqAlsaadi I'm sorry, but I don't know what that means. The `chull` variable is from your question, so it is already based on your equation.